# How to set flag Yes or No in the sql select when using values in in the sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

How to set flag Yes or No in the sql select when using values in  in the sql server
Suppose Table A column has 100 values,
when I do select A from Table where A in ('2','3')

I want the result like

```
A     Flag
----------
1     No
2     Yes
3     Yes
4     No
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `case`:

```
select t.*,
    case when a in (2, 3) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as flag
from mytable t
```

Side note: it looks like `a` is a number, so I compared it against literal numbers (without surrounding single quotes). Using the proper datatype for comparisons is a best practice, and avoids somehow subtle traps.

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative for **CASE**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Col INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)

SELECT * ,IIF(Col IN (2,3),'Yes','No') AS Flag
FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to replace values is to treat the values as a reference table.   You can do this in the `from` clause:

```
select t.*, coalesce(v.flag, 'No')
from t left join
     (values (2, 'Yes'), (3, 'Yes')) v(a, flag)
     on t.a = v.a;
```

This suggests that the Yes/No value should actually be stored in a reference table.  If you have a reference table for `a`, then that would be a natural place for such information.